# Trilled R between a vowel and a consonant

Tags: phonetics, russian, trills, finnish, ukrainian

Take the Finnish word **Terve /tɛrʋɛ/** as an example, how to pronounce the R which comes after a vowel and is followed by a consonant? I have listened to some samples but they just sound like a tapped R, not a trilled R, and it seems so difficult to produce a completely trilled R at that position, the same happens to me for Russian and Ukrainian languages, could someone please explain it? Thank you.

Comment: I don’t find it particularly hard to pronounce a trill in that position, but the tap/trill distinction is weaker than other single/geminate contrasts. Note also that the tap always realisation corresponds to the non-geminate phoneme, which is usually written /r/ for simplicity (even though that’s the trill character in IPA). The trill archetypically corresponds to the geminate /r:/, but is also possible in most cases of non-geminate /r/. The reverse is not true, however: a tap for a geminate /r:/ does not generally occur.

Comment: Here's a good audio sample, the Russian verb _рвать_ [rvatʲ] https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/рвать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what your acoustic models are, so perhaps the individual saying the words are not producing trills. Here are some examples of the Finnish word [perkele](https://forvo.com/word/perkele/#fi), [järvi](https://forvo.com/word/j%C3%A4rvi/#fi), [terve](https://forvo.com/word/terve/#fi) and [sormi](https://forvo.com/word/sormi/#fi). You can't compare trilled *r* in Finnish to tapped *r*, because there is only one rhotic in the language. You can find intervocalic trills vs. taps in Spanish, signaled as *rr* vs *r* in the classic minimal pairs pero – perro, caro – carro, quería – querría.

The best way to develop the ability to perceive a pre-consonantal trill is to start with an intervocalic trill in a known case, thus Spanish or Italian *caro* vs. *carro*. Obviously you need real data, so you need a speaker of the language (that's why I'm naming less-obscure languages). You can use Forvo except that it may be hard to find the same person saying *carro* vs *caro* do you won't know if the difference is just because two people have different speech equipment. Ideally, you would obtain samples, you could listen and hear the difference; and in Praat, looking at spectrograms, you can see the difference.

I do not know of any language that has a robust contrast between trill and tap in VRC.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean by not being able to compare trilled and tapped _r_ in Finnish. /r/, like any other consonant in Finnish, distinguishes length, and non-geminate /r/ is typically tapped. It _may_ be trilled (more briefly than /r:/), which is where it differs from its Spanish counterpart, but it’s easy enough to find pairs like _muren_ ‘crumb’ vs _murren_ ‘pooch (gen.sg.)’ realised as tap/trill pairs, just as they would be in Spanish.